# Assign control variables in for loop python

Tags: python

I have binary vectors X1 through X6 and Y1 through Y6. I want to find the outer product between each vector in X and its corresponding vector in Y, e.g. outer product of (X1,Y1) , outer product of (X2,Y2) and so on. I am using numpy.outer(X1, Y1). Now I want to generate a for loop to go through all of them and then OR their outputs together. Below is my code I get the error "SyntaxError: can't assign to operator" when I remove the %d beside the w on the LHS of the equation I get another error that X isn't defined. So, can anybody help me on how to solve this issue.

```
X1=[1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
X2=[0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
X3=[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
X4=[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
X5=[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
X6=[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]

Y1=[[1], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
Y2=[[0], [0], [1], [0], [0]]
Y3=[[0], [1], [0], [0], [0]]
Y4=[[0], [0], [0], [1], [0]]
Y5=[[0], [0], [0], [0], [1]]
Y6=[[0], [0], [0], [1], [0]]

w=(5,5)
wt= np.zeros((w),dtype=np.integer)

for i in range (1, 6):
    w%d=np.outer(X%d,Y%d) % (i, i, i)
    wt=wt or w%d % i
print wt
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your expected output to question?

Comment: what did you expect `w%d=np.outer(X%d,Y%d) % (i, i, i)` to do exactly?

Comment: **1st iteration:**,
    'w1=np.outer(X1,Y1)',
    'wt = wt or w1',
**2nd iteration:**,
    'w2=np.outer(X2,Y2)',
    'wt= wt or w2',
and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to put your variables in an array:

```
X = [X1, X2, ..., X6]
Y = [Y1, Y2, ..., Y6]
```

That way:

```
W = [np.outer(x, y) for (x,y) in zip(X,Y)]
wt = reduce(lambda a,b: a or b,
            W,
            np.zeros((5,5),dtype=np.integer))
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I get the error "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"